# Display table fields in a single query

Tags: php, sql

**`user_info`** table:

- `ui_id` - PK
- `name`
- `created_by` - FK

`users` table:

- `user_id`- PK
- `username`

I want to display the content of `user_info` table. The `created_by` field are `user_id`s from users table, I want to change it into `username` when displaying it.

Is it possible in a single query? Please tell me how.

Comment: Why there are two name columns? one `name` in `user_info` and the other `username` in `users` table? you might need to remove one of them.

Comment: I forgot to add another field in user_info table, that should have user_id FK to users table to determine which user he/she is. The user_info table are the information of users in users table, the created by field also came from users table. So I can't remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do

```
select ui.*, u.username from user_info ui
join users u on u.id = ui.created_by
```

Simply join the tables.

Comment: its an alias for the table names. I think you better go through some quick tutorials on sql

Comment: thanks. What if i add another field(modified_by) in user_info which will get also the username from users table?

Comment: if you want to get modifed by username, then join the users table with that field. if you want to get both created by, modified users, you have to join users table twice

Comment: I tried this `SELECT ui.name,u.username FROM user_info ui JOIN users u ON u.user_id = ui.created_by 
AND JOIN users u.user_id = modified_by` but there's syntax error. What to do?

Comment: use this SELECT ui.name,u.username as user_created, um.username as user_modified FROM user_info ui JOIN users u ON u.user_id = ui.created_by JOIN users um um.user_id = ui.modified_by;         ............... You should go through some quick tutorials on sql